# how to get json data in different veriables in laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel

i am getting response in `return response()->json(['data' => $res]);`

```
array:2 [▼
  "response" => "{"ResCode":"TPB013","ResMsg":"Invalid BAR code, please refresh","ResStatus":1,"sign":"w0EQNoxIOkl0K3IKZYKJEPojBrHerRwdTHS4fhAz3n9CxfIprH0QklzgdNaWWzwmBUq++h2U43 ▶"
  "http_code" => 200
]
{#576 ▼
  +"ResCode": "TPB013"
  +"ResMsg": "Invalid BAR code, please refresh"
  +"ResStatus": 1
  +"sign": "w0EQNoxIOkl0K3IKZYKJEPojBrHerRwdTHS4fhAz3n9CxfIprH0QklzgdNaWWzwmBUq++h2U432d4s5uHmCTjA=="
}
```

**i want that i get all the response in different veriables like this**

```
$responcse = //json res
$http_code = //json res
$ResCode   = //json res
$ResMsg    = //json res
$ResStatus = //json res
$sign      = //json res
```

how i can do that in laravel i dont know how to handle json response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be basic PHP, using json_decode you can get each value.

```
$data = json_decode($res['response']);

$data = // response
$res['http_code'] = // http_code
$data->ResCode 
$data->ResMsg
$data->ResStatus
$data->sign
```

Answer (score 2):

Use php's [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function:

```php
$response["test"] = 123;
extract($response);
var_dump($test);
```